# Invalid Operation Exception in file saving

Tags: c#, file

I have this code and I don't know why it pops up this error message :

> "Invalid Operation Exception was unhandled by user code".

This error comes out when I press the save button.

The purpose of this program is to save the text from one textbox in the Mytest.txt file and then from the file to the textbox1. I would really appreciate some help here. 
Thank you in advance.

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void buttonsave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string path = @"C:\Users\geora\Mytest.txt";
        if(!File.Exists(path))
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(textBox.Text);
            }
        }
    }

    private void buttonshow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string path = @"C:\Users\geora\Mytest.txt";
        using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(path))
        {
            string s = "";
            s = sr.ReadLine();
            textBox1.Text = s;
        }
    }
```

Comment: at which line does the exception occur?

Comment: You're code seems absolutely fine (almost copied from msdn example), please add the details of the exception (the exact message and _where_ it is raised).

Comment: Yeah. Sorry for not telling this before. My fault. The error mentions the code : "File.CreateText(path))" at the 10th line.

Comment: I cannot reproduce that. If you were lacking access rights at that directory (first guess), there would be an `UnauthorizedException`....What framework and device are you running thist at? I remember reading about those exceptions using `File` in UWP or .net-core apps....

Comment: Can you verify that .NET Target Framework version is correct?

Answer (score 1):

You have opened files but not  closed the file.This Might be the issue

```
StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(path)
```

You need to close it. Using does this for you (and disposes it so it's GC'd sooner):

Or alternatively in .Net 2 you can use the new File. static members, then you don't need to close anything:

```
variable = File.ReadAllText(path);
```

Comment: The exception is raised while _saving_, not _reading_. And `File.CreateText()` creates _and opens_ the file, returning the desired `StreamWriter`.

Answer (score 0):

Additional to your exception
WPF Version:

```
private void loadButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    textBox.Text = File.ReadAllText(@"d:\test.txt");
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
  }
}

private void saveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    File.WriteAllText(@"d:\test.txt", textBox.Text);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
  }
}
```

UWP Version:

```
using System;
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.UI.Popups;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
...
private async void buttonSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    var storageFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    var sampleFile = await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync("sample.txt",
      CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(sampleFile, textBox.Text);

    var msgbox = new MessageDialog(sampleFile.Path, "Your file is in");
    await msgbox.ShowAsync();
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    var msgbox = new MessageDialog(ex.ToString(), "Error");
    await msgbox.ShowAsync();
  }
}

private async void buttonLoad_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    var storageFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    var sampleFile = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync("sample.txt");
    textBox.Text = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(sampleFile);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    var msgbox = new MessageDialog(ex.ToString(), "Error");
    await msgbox.ShowAsync();
  }
}
```

Comment: No but it might give a hint where to search? The creator of this topic may post the concrete exception message or examine it by himself.

Comment: It shows the same error in the "File.WriteAllText" line. Also the error window says : "Additional information: Synchronous operations should not be performed on the UI thread.  Consider wrapping this method in Task.Run."

Comment: I am using universal windows applications in c#. If this helps a bit.

Comment: @GeorakosGeor take a look at UWP version, writing it also for the first time, but it works.